# Mysterious trouble with escaping quotes in C#

Tags: c#

I have no idea even where to start on this problem. I'm trying to do something very simple, create a string with quotation marks in it. I have no problem (even in C#) with this, but this one particular chunk of code is behaving very oddly (at least by my know-how).

```
Match timeExtractor = (new Regex(@"'(?<time>\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'")).Match(SQLstatement);
string time = timeExtractor.Groups["time"].ToString();
Match visitIDExtractor = (new Regex(@"VALUES\('(?<visit_id>[\d]+)'")).Match(SQLstatement);
string visit_id = visitIDExtractor.Groups["visit_id"].ToString();
string s = "Select * From MeasurementsData Where Time =\"" + time + "\" AND Visit_ID =\"" + visit_id + "\";";
queryCommand.CommandText = s;
```

My problem is my resulting string looks something along the lines of:

"Select * From MeasurementsData Where Time = \"2009:11:11 11:11:11\" AND Visit_ID...."

With the backslashes appearing in the expression. The following test code run in another application produces the results I desire (the ones without the backslashes)

```
string time = @"2009:11:11 11:11:11";
string visit_id = @"1279";
string s = "Select * From MeasurementsData Where Time =\"" + time + "\" AND Visit_ID =\"" + visit_id + "\";";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

These desired results are produced with or without the preceding @ symbol. I fiddled with it for a while.

Adding an extra backslash escapes the backslash and not the quotes (as I believe it should) and doesn't escape the quotes so it doesn't compile.

Removing the backslash treats caused the quote not to be escaped and once again it will not compile (as I expected).

But this is what really gets me. I try just removing the backslashes with the following addition to the code:

```
Match timeExtractor = (new Regex(@"'(?<time>\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'")).Match(SQLstatement);
string time = timeExtractor.Groups["time"].ToString();
Match visitIDExtractor = (new Regex(@"VALUES\('(?<visit_id>[\d]+)'")).Match(SQLstatement);
string visit_id = visitIDExtractor.Groups["visit_id"].ToString();
string s = "Select * From MeasurementsData Where Time =\"" + time + "\" AND Visit_ID =\"" + visit_id + "\";";
s = s.Replace("\\", "");
queryCommand.CommandText = s;
```

And it doesn't do anything to the string! It still contains the backslashes. I need someone with more experience than myself to show me what I'm doing wrong or how to get around this behavior.

Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: Are you just looking at the s variable in the debugger/ide?  In the debugger/ide, it will show with the escaped characters as slash quote, but in the real string, it will just contain the quote.

Comment: @cons: I didn't see your comment up here before, so I posted an answer after you posted your comment. You're right. I verified it by running his code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should go with:

```
queryCommand.CommandText = "Select * From MeasurementsData " + 
                           "Where Time =@Time AND Visit_ID =@VisitId;";
queryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", time);
queryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitId", visit_id);
```

This way you don't need to put those quotes and it's safe against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: +1.  I wish I could give more than one vote.  Contencating strings like shown in the question is a huge security no-no.  http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Okay, I've seen it done that way before, but would Time and visit_id be encapsulated in quotes?

Comment: using parameters you don't need to use quotes, Chad; try it =)

Comment: Good point, even if this isn't too high of a priority, I should get into the practice. But does this solve my issues with the quotes?

Comment: @Chad - no, because you want to use the values of those variables, not their name.

Comment: I'd vote this up more than once if I could.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters

Comment: If you look below, you can see I have posted a solution to your issue. You can use the time you saved not having to debug this further to learn how to use parameters. It's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use single quotes instead?

```
string s = "Select * From MeasurementsData Where Time='" + time + "' AND Visit_ID='" + visit_id + "';";
```

Answer (score 2):

when using the '@' sign, there is no "escape slash".
using the '@' sign you can write all chars literally without any escaping, except that the quotes char " should be writed twice to consider as one.

Answer (score 2):

`@"\"blah\""` will produce `\"blah\"`. `@"""blah"""` will produce `"blah"`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're looking at the string in the debugger, and the debugger is escaping it.

If you add this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

you'll see that the string is in fact correct!

```
Select * From MeasurementsData Where Time ="2009:12:01 12:00:00" AND Visit_ID ="10012";
```

(And I agree with others that you shouldn't be creating SQL by building up strings, send the data to the database using query parameters instead).